# trying to get an if statement to be triggered during certain times of day

Tags: python

im fairly new with python but im tring to get a device to turn on for one minute and off for 3 minutes repeatedly from the times of 9am to 5pm and i can't get the if statement to reference the updated time from the loop any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
import datetime
import time
n = "on" #to be replaced with GPIO output
f = "off" #to be replaced with GPIO output
nt = "tis not be the time" #used to see if working or not
tt = "tis be time" #used to see if working or not
now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
def count():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = now.second
    total = 1
    if hour >= 8 and hour <= 16:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        hour = now.hour
        for i in range(1,100):
            total = total*2
            print (tt)
            print (n)
            time.sleep(60)
            print(f)
            time.sleep(180)
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            hour = now.second
            print (hour)
    else :
        for i in range(1,100):
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            hour = now.hour
            print (nt)
            print (hour)
            time.sleep(10)
count()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Your if statement is outside of both loops, it is never executed once the loops start running and resetting the now time.

Comment: Inside the loop `if not (hour >= 8 and hour <= 16): break`

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it with a while loop instead, it would look like this, just put all of it inside your function

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
if hour >= 8 and hour <= 16:
    run = True
else:
    run = False
while run:
    total = total*2
    print (tt)
    print (n)
    time.sleep(60)
    print(f)
    time.sleep(180)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = now.second
    print (hour)
    if hour >= 8 and hour <= 16:
        run = True
    else:
        run = False

while run == False:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = now.hour
    print (nt)
    print (hour)
    time.sleep(10)
    if hour >= 8 and hour <= 16:
        run = True
    else:
        run = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a while statement. In addition, you have `hour = now.second` on the second line of the function count and I think it should be `hour = now.hour`.

See the code with comments:

```
import datetime
import time
n = "on" #to be replaced with GPIO output
f = "off" #to be replaced with GPIO output
nt = "tis not be the time" #used to see if working or not
tt = "tis be time" #used to see if working or not
#Next lines are redundant, commented out.
#now = datetime.datetime.now()
#hour = now.hour

def count():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = now.hour #now.second
    total = 1
    while hour >= 8 and hour <= 16:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        hour = now.hour
        # for i in range(1,100): -> why you need this?
        total = total*2
        print (tt)
        print (n)
        time.sleep(60)
        print(f)
        time.sleep(180)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        hour = now.hour #now.second
        print (hour)
    for i in range(1,100): #I don't know why you need a loop here
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        hour = now.hour
        print (nt)
        print (hour)
        time.sleep(10)
count()
```

Edited for correcting another `hour = now.second` inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are you planning on running the code, but the main problem I see is that you do not have any loop for your code to run infinitely and check the time condition.

Also it's not clear for me why you need this `total` variable that gets doubled.
Another thing is your `for` loops - the condition is not clear. Why do you want to run it in this specific range?

What I would do is I would create an infinite loop and inside it make some decisions based on a clear time conditions - the conditions that are specified by you.
So if I understood your case correctly I'd rather write something like this:

```
# between 9am to 5pm turn on the device for 60 seconds and off for 180 seconds repeatedly 

from datetime import datetime
import time


def update_device_state(state):
    # TODO: implement GPIO output code
    pass


def run():
    device_state = 'off'
    new_state = device_state
    on_timer = 0
    off_timer = time.time() - 180 # initial value must be over 180 seconds to trigger device on a first run
    while True:
        hour = datetime.now().hour
        if 5 <= hour <= 17:
            if device_state == 'off' and time.time() - off_timer > 180:
                on_timer = time.time()
                new_state = 'on'
                off_timer = 0
            elif device_state == 'on' and time.time() - on_timer > 60:
                off_timer = time.time()
                new_state = 'off'
                on_timer = 0
        else:
            if device_state = 'on'
                new_state = 'off'
                on_timer = 0
                off_timer = time.time()
        if device_state != new_state:
            update_device_state(new_state)
            device_state = new_state
        time.sleep(1)

run()
```

But the code requires some testing as I just quickly drafted it and I just briefly red it.